# Open eaves vs soffits

Tags: roof, roofing

My house has a 12" overhang with open eave vents. I am planning to put in a ridge vent, and have read it mentioned that soffits work better with ridge vents. I can't see how it would make a difference, am I correct in this assumption? would adding soffits improve airflow to the ridge vent?

Comment: With open eaves how do you keep critters out? But they are basically the same as far as functionality it is all based on the number of square inches of opening.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that soffits are the preferred option over open eaves (due to Ed Beal’s comment about keeping critters out). Either option will allow the ridge vent to evacuate the warm air and enable a convection current but the soffits will keep critters out.  Why invite bats, mud daubers, etc. in?